# Workflow Details from Instance ID

Tags: 2013, workflow

I have workflow instance causing workflow manager backend service to crash. I want to delete this instance. I only know the instance ID of the workflow, how can i get the details, such as Item Id, List ID, Site name?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following Script

```
$site = Get-SPSite "http://epm"
$wfinstanceid="c3dfe396-ba8c-4937-a626-a8e2382f01f4" 
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
{

 foreach ($list in $web.Lists) 
 { 
   foreach ($wf in $list.WorkFlowAssociations) 
    {   
     if($wf.id -eq $wfinstanceid){  
      write-host "Workflow -->" $wf.Name 
      write-host "Parent Site -->" $wf.ParentSite 
      write-host "Parent Web -->" $wf.ParentWeb
      write-host "List Title -->" $wf.ParentList
      write-host "List Title -->" $wf.TaskListTitle
     }
    }

 }
}
$web.Dispose()
$site.Dispose()
```

**output**

[image]

**Note:**

- Replace $site with your site collection URL.
- Replace `$wfinstanceid` with your workflowID.
- To get more details from the current available data in if condition above add `$wf.` and click tab button from keyboard and check the available property.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the script, couldn't match with the instance ID i had though.  I had received this Workflow Instance from WF DB.